# No italics in algorithm2e if-clause

Tags: fonts, punctuation, algorithms, algorithm2e

Why does `algorithm2e` typeset the variables `anychange` and `done` in italics, and how can I turn this off? How can I remove the semicolon after `done` in the `until`-clause?

[image]

```
$\textsf{anychange} \gets \textsf{false}$ \\
\Repeat{$\textsf{done}$}{

    $\textsf{done} \gets \textsf{true}$ \\
    \ParallelFor{$u \in V$} {
        $\delta \gets \max_{v \in N(u)} \left \{ \Delta mod(v, \zeta(u) \rightarrow \zeta(v)) \right \} $\\
        $C \gets \zeta(\arg\max_{v \in N(u)} \left \{ \Delta mod(v, \zeta(u) \rightarrow \zeta(v)) \right \} ) $\\
        \If{$\delta > 0$}{
            $\zeta(u) \leftarrow C$ \\
            $\textsf{done} \gets \textsf{false}$ \\
            $\textsf{anychange} \gets \textsf{true}$ \\
        }
    }
}
\If{$\textsf{anychange}$}{
    $G' \leftarrow$ \textsf{contract}$(G, \zeta)$ \\
    $\zeta \gets$ \textsf{prolong(PLM$(G')$)} \\
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) provides `\DontPrintSemicolon` to avoid printing the `;` at the end of statements. Conditional arguments to structures are set in *italics*. You can override this using the occasional as-needed `\upshape`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
$\textsf{anychange} \gets \textsf{false}$ \\
\Repeat{$\textsf{\upshape done}$}{

    $\textsf{done} \gets \textsf{true}$ \\
    \For{$u \in V$} {
        $\delta \gets \max_{v \in N(u)} \left \{ \Delta mod(v, \zeta(u) \rightarrow \zeta(v)) \right \} $\\
        $C \gets \zeta(\arg\max_{v \in N(u)} \left \{ \Delta mod(v, \zeta(u) \rightarrow \zeta(v)) \right \} ) $\\
        \If{$\delta > 0$}{
            $\zeta(u) \leftarrow C$ \\
            $\textsf{done} \gets \textsf{false}$ \\
            $\textsf{anychange} \gets \textsf{true}$ \\
        }
    }
}
\If{$\textsf{\upshape anychange}$}{
    $G' \leftarrow$ \textsf{contract}$(G, \zeta)$ \\
    $\zeta \gets$ \textsf{prolong(PLM$(G')$)} \\
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can one switch this italic font in conditional arguments generally off?

Comment: @Arne: This is governed by `\ArgSty` - an `Arg`ument `Sty`le function, which can be adjusted via `\SetArgSty`. Try, for example, `\SetArgSty{upshape}` to force a specific (`up`right) `shape`. Similar alternatives include `\SetArgSty{relax}` (`\relax` is just a no-op) and `\SetArgSty{textnormal}`, which is the current "exterior" default switch to remove any kind of formatting/shape.

Comment: Thanks, Werner!