# Algorithm2e - Permanent fix for no italics if-clause

Tags: formatting, algorithm2e

I am using [algorithm2e](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) to create pseudocode for my document. However, it has it so that the conditions in `if` clauses are italicised.

[This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102935/29171) suggests putting an `\upshape` in each if condition. Is there a permanent fix to set the `if` condition to never be italics?

For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\Begin{
    Flag $\leftarrow$ True\;
    \If{Flag}{
        DoSomething()\;
    }
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I don't want `Flag` to be italicised without having to put an `\upshape` in the condition, or have to do multiple fixes for each condition in an algorithm.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please always post *complete* small document that shows the problem and allows answers to be tested. The package allows you to go

```
\SetArgSty{textrm}
```

to replace the default `emph` but that affects several components not just if clauses so might be more than you want.