# Algorithm2e - Permanent fix for no italics if-clause for all document

Tags: formatting, algorithm2e

I am using algorithm2e to write algorithms, and I use the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110674/algorithm2e-permanent-fix-for-no-italics-if-clause?noredirect=1&lq=1) to prevent the text in the algorithm to be in italic (by adding `\SetArgSty{textrm}` at the start of the algorithm).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetArgSty{textrm}  % <-'Flag' will not be written in italic
\Begin{
    Flag $\leftarrow$ True\;
    \If{Flag}{
        DoSomething()\;
    }
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

There are several algorithms in my document, and it is typically the kind of thing I like to have factored at the start of the document rather than to write it in each and every algorithm.

I am wondering, is there a way to have this working for all the algorithms in my document ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with help of the package `etoolbox` and its macro `\AtBeginEnvironment`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithm}{\SetArgSty{textrm}}  % <-'Flag' will not be written in italic

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\Begin{
    Flag $\leftarrow$ True\;
    \If{Flag}{
        DoSomething()\;
    }
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: works as a charm, thanks !