# Disable italics in algorithm2e program name

Tags: algorithm2e

I want to disable globally the italics style in the program names.

I have seen [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102933/no-italics-in-algorithm2e-if-clause) which is on a similar question, and which suggests to use `\SetArgSty{upshape}` to disable globally italics in if conditions of algorithm2e.
I want to do the same, but for program names.
On the [algorithm2e manual](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf), I have seen that there exists a similar `\SetProgSty` command, however it does not seem to solve my problem:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vlined,boxed,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\SetProgSty{upshape}
\SetKwProg{Operation}{operation}{ is}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
    \Operation{add\_one$(x)$}{\textsf{return} $x+1$}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

What I get:

[image: wig]

What I want:

[image: wiw]

I have tried all other `\Set...Sty` commands, and I have also tried `relax` and `textnormal` instead of `upshape`, but nothing seems to work.

How to do that please?

Comment: `algorithm2e` is a really good package but it is funny in the same breath, defines things itself without using other packages like `caption` etc, it is not the easiest package but does work when you know how to go through the source code, I highly recommend going through `algorithm2e.sty` contained on Overleaf, TeXlive or whichever you use as you get more confident with the code/styles etc. Hope my answer helps!

Comment: You should type `\Operation{$\mathrm{add\_one}(x)$}{\textsf{return} $x+1$}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vlined,boxed,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\SetProgSty{upshape}
\SetKwProg{Operation}{operation}{ is}{}

\renewcommand{\ProgSty}[1]{\textnormal{#1}\unskip} % removed \emph{}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
    \Operation{add\_one$(x)$}{\textsf{return} $x+1$}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]